# In Cloudfoundry the URL of an application is

Tags: cloud-foundry

In Cloudfoundry what is the URL of an application?

Is it of the type Domain.subdomain or subdomain.domain?

Comment: Or is it just Domain or just subdomain

Comment: mostly `app-name.domain-name` and to be technically correct, it is `host-name.domain-name`

Comment: So each application needs to have a unique host-name or a unique domain-name?

Comment: unique `host-name` is fine. The `host-name.domain-name` combination is unique and will not be used for another App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot. When you push your application, you can do nothing and rely on the defaults. The default will be for a route to be mapped to your app that is `app-name.default-domain`. You as a developer will set the app name and your platform operator will pick the default domain. There may be other domains available, but there's always at least one which is the default domain for apps.

Beyond that, you can control what routes are mapped to your app. If you include a `manifest.yml` file, you can include a `routes:` block, which lets you add one or more routes to your app.

Ex:

```
- routes:
  - route: www.example.com
  - route: www.example-other.com
```

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#routes

You could also `cf push --no-start` your app, then run `cf map-route` to add routes and finally run `cf start`. That would be if you're not using a manifest.yml file.

Other interesting things you can do:

- `cf push --no-route` which doesn't assign any route. This is useful for non-web apps.
- `cf push --random-route` which generates a random host name instead of using your app's name.
- `cf push --route-path` which allows you to map not only a domain, but also a path. Ex: `www.example.com/api/v2` would send only requests to `/api/v2` to the given app.

Historically, you could set `domain`, `domains`, `host` and `hosts` in your manifest.yml file and you'd get various combinations of routes mapped to your app. These options have been deprecated though and shouldn't be used going forward.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#route-attribute